# How do you remove extension from RefineryCMS Admin area?

Tags: refinerycms

I removed an extension from RefineryCMS but the tab for that extension is still in RefineryCMS admin area.

Answer (score 0):

Most engine installs come with a database migration. Look in db/migrate and identify any migrations associated with the engine. Then:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=<number of migration to reverse>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
rails destroy refinery:engine [refinery-engine-name]
```